# How to diagnose/fix envoy proxy "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure"

Tags: nginx, envoyproxy

I have a service mesh envoy proxy configuration issue. The configuration is based on this example from the official envoy proxy site: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/sandboxes/front_proxy, and this ssl lesson: https://www.envoyproxy.io/learn/ssl.

I have tried many different combinations of ports (80,443), namings, domains, nginx config etc..., nothing works.

Here is my front-proxy:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    listener_filters:
      - name: "envoy.listener.tls_inspector"
        typed_config: {}
    filter_chains:
    - filter_chain_match:
        server_names: ["example.com", "www.example.com", "api.example.com", "test.example.com"]
      tls_context:
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.pem"
              private_key:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.key"
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
            - name: envoy.file_access_log
              config:
                path: "/var/log/access.log"
          route_config:
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: services
              domains:
              - ["*.example.com","example.com"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                redirect:
                  path_redirect: "/"
                  https_redirect: true
          http_filters:
            - name: envoy.router
              config: {}
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 443
    listener_filters:
      - name: "envoy.listener.tls_inspector"
        typed_config: {}
    filter_chains:
    - filter_chain_match:
        server_names: ["api.example.com"]
      tls_context:
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.pem"
              private_key:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.key"
      filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: api
              domains:
              - ["*.example.com","example.com"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/v1"
                route:
                  cluster: api
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
            - name: envoy.file_access_log
              config:
                path: "/var/log/access.log"
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: services
              domains:
              - ["*.example.com","example.com"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/v1"
                route:
                  cluster: api
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: frontend
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            config: {}
      tls_context:
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.pem"
              private_key:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.key"

  clusters:
  - name: frontend
    connect_timeout: 1s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    # http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: frontend
        port_value: 80
  - name: api
    connect_timeout: 1s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    # http2_protocol_options: {}
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: api
        port_value: 80
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

and the upstream service that is a connnection failure:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
      tls_context:
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.pem"
              private_key:
                filename: "/etc/example-ai.key"
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
            - name: envoy.file_access_log
              config:
                path: "/var/log/access.log"
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: api
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/v1"
                route:
                  cluster: local_api
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            typed_config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: local_api
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: local_api
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 443
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8082
```

and here is the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

```
map $http_origin $cors_header {
    default "";
    "~^https?://[^/]+\.example\.ai(:[0-9]+)?$" "$http_origin";
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.ai;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    index index.html;

    location / {


      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'api.example.ai' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
      # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
      #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;


      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
      }

      # render react page refreshes
      if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
      }

      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Any troubleshooting tips appreciated!

Comment: I suggest, go in following order to try things: 1. Try hitting the backend services directly (hit envoy if service is behind another envoy), 2. Check cluster configuration (check if correct address is used, if possible add healthcheck), 3. Remove all unrequired configurations from front proxy and provide one filter (like you have redirect configuration)

Comment: Also, add healthcheck in service envoy for service so if incase service is down, you can clearly see healthcheck failure logs in service envoy

Comment: Have you tried turning debug mode for envoy ('-l debug')? I was getting the same error and debug indicated that I needed to enable http2 in my cluster.

Comment: what's the update on this issue, were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, too. I changed my application's service.yaml.

```
    service:
      type: ClusterIP
      port: 8080
```